# Unable to boot on newest kernel-headers, can't find data volume

Tags: boot

After a recent update to the kernel headers (I believe), the system cannot boot correctly off the newest initrd iamge (5.11.0-34). It can still boot if I go into the advanced options in GRUB and select (5.11.0-27). The boot up screen just spins, and if I hit escape I see an error message to the effect of being unable to find the "data" volume/volume group.

I have already tried recreating the initrd image and updating the grub configuration with update-initramfs and update-grub.

Comment: That is unlikely to be an elementary-specific problem. I think you'll have better luck asking on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: Same problem, makes no sense to have an elementary site with questions to be redirected to a different product site if we are not using it.

Comment: here the xorg logs from trying startx https://pastebin.com/aZKM1VXB

Comment: I have the drivers installed and have no problem with the old kernel, only the newer kernel this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually ended up figuring out how to fix it from a live iso (had to as the older initrd image I was previously using also stopped working). I imagine anything would work but for the sake of completeness I used a Fedora 34 live ISO.

1. Boot into Live ISO
2. Open a terminal and run sudo su (for convenience)
3. Figure out which device has your luks partition if encryption is in play (mine was /dev/nvme0n1p3)
4. Run `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p3 cryptdata`
5. Run `vgchange -ay`
6. Run the following `mount` commands

```
mount /dev/mapper/data-root /mnt
mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt/boot (substitute nvme0n1p2 for whatever your boot partition is)
mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc
mount -t sysfs sysfs /mnt/sys
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
```

7. Run `chroot /mnt`
8. Run `apt install lvm2 cryptsetup-initramfs`
9. Run `update-initramfs -c -k all`

A few additional notes:

1. If you did not enable encryption in the installer you may not need to do any of the steps involving cryptsetup. You may not need to do the `vgchange` either as I'm not sure whether LVM is used when you don't enable encryption during installation.
2. Make sure your live environment has internet, and if you get name resolution errors in the chroot environment then you may need to edit `/etc/resolv.conf` to add a known-good DNS nameserver (such as Google's public DNS 8.8.8.8)
3. If you get a warning during the `update-initramfs` about cryptdata not being found, then you'll need to check your `/etc/crypttab` to see what the name is in there (should be at the beginning of the first line). Then you'll need to unmount everything, run `vgchange -an` to deactivate the logical volumes, run `cryptesetup luksClose cryptdata` to close the luks encrypted partition, and then repeat the steps, substituting the name from `/etc/crypttab` in place of cryptdata.